# Mouse events and brush in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently attempting to customize the example of a time serie chart found at http://nvd3.com/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html. This is implemented using nvd3, a library on top of d3. I would like to have tooltips for data points as in the top graph but would also like be able to select a range in the *same* graph like in the bottom "view finder" graph in the example.

To that end, I've added a "brush" to the example of a basic line chart (see http://nvd3.com/ghpages/line.html). The range selection works like a charm, however, tooltips for data points don't work anymore, except for points which are just out of the range of the axes. It seems, that the data points lying in the brush area don't get the mouse events anymore and that the brush absorbs them all.

What needs to be changed that the data points of the lines receive mouse events (in particular mouseover, I don't care about click)?

An attempt would be to catch all events using

```
d3.select(window).on("...", function)
```

and then trigger some "mouseover" event over data points if applicable. How could this be achieved (I don't wan't go through all data points and then check which one is closest to the mouseevent...)? Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 13):

If you will *Inspect element* (Chorme) anywhere on the 'brush' you will notice the  element that is built after your other graphical elements that you're trying to catch events on.

The d3.brush function is creating a hidden background to catch the mouse events.

```
// An invisible, mouseable area for starting a new brush.
      bg.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "background")
          .style("visibility", "hidden")
          .style("cursor", "crosshair");
```

So the solution is to call the brush **before** plotting your data (lines, paths, scatter plot circles etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Since the brush overlay will grab your mouse events - and you need it to - I am not sure you can get around this. Ultimately event bubbling only works for the DOM tree, and these elements will be siblings at best.

Possibly instead of iterating over all data points you can iterate only those that are selected by the brush. Check out [d3.touches(container)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_touches)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. I realized that the brush overlaid the other objects (in my case were circles). So, first I created the brush rect, Then I created other objects. This way I could access to other objects' events as well.