# D3 updating brush's scale doesn't update brush

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

What I want to create is a zoomable, brushable timeline in D3 version 3.5.6. For now I'm not using D3's zoom behavior but just two zoom buttons. My problem is the following: When a button is clicked, I update the scale and redraw the axis as well as the brush. For some reason the brush doesn't update the extent rectangle and the handles but just the background. I know that I'm not actually updating the `.extent()` of the brush. But isn't the brush supposed to update when the scale was changed?

Here's the relevant portion of the code. The rest can be found in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azksfjjw/).

```
document.getElementById('in').addEventListener('click', zoom.bind(null, .1));
document.getElementById('out').addEventListener('click', zoom.bind(null, -.1));

function zoom(step) {
  var offset;

  zoomScale += step;

  if(zoomScale < 1)
    zoomScale -= step;

  offset = (zoomScale * width - width) / 2;

  // updating the scale
  xScale
    .range([-offset, width + offset]);

  // redrawing the brush which doesn't seem to have effect I expected
  brushGroup
    .call(brush);

  // redrawing the axis which works fine
  xAxisGroup
    .transition()
    .call(xAxis);      
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you need to reset the brush's extent, so the internal `xExtent` and `yExtent` variables are reset. Seems like a bug to me.

```
brush.extent(brush.extent());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azksfjjw/6/

Answer (score 2):

I caught the problem in your zoom function you re define xScale range as

```
 xScale
    .range([-offset, width + offset]);
```

After this you need to pass it here

```
brush = d3.svg.brush()
          .x(xScale) // This need new Values 
          .extent([.1, .6]),
```

Than after you can call to re draw your time line

```
 brushGroup
        .call(brush);
```

here the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/azksfjjw/4/

Comment: Yess thanks a lot for your answer! This seems to work but I'm a bit confused. Isn't a brush supposed to save the scale passed to its `.scale()`function? As far as I know the same goes for axes. If their scales change the only thing you have to do is call them again, no? Are brushes different in that respect?

Comment: I can't find a reverence to the .x(xScale) for brushes. i don't think that's the current way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by deleting the brush group and calling it again.

Before graph resizing:

```
var brush = d3.brushX().extent([[0, 0], [graph_dim.w, graph_dim.h]]).on("end", brushended);
graphContent.append("g").attr("class", "brush").call(brush);
```

After graph resizing:

```
// update graph height 
graph_dim.h = my_new_graph_height;

// update brush extent
brush.extent([[0, 0], [graph_dim.w, graph_dim.h]]);
graphDIV.select(".brush").remove();
graphContent.append("g").attr("class", "brush").call(brush);
```

Probably not the best way, but it works :-)

NOTE that if you have mouse events on the same graph, they will no longer be accessible (the brush will "cover" them) -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13818606/3005925).